# What is the speed of ISS relative to ground surface?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, low-earth-orbit

Is it 7660 m/s or (7660-460)m/s? If it is the former then the ISS orbits about the Earth at 8120 m/s.

I think it should be  (7660-460)m/s relative to ground based on this orbital period formula, $$T=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{r^3}{GM}}$$.

Comment: You’re correct.

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: Your calculation ignores the inclination of the ISS orbit of 51.64 degrees.

Comment: [This Scott Manley video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_zApGNHOi0s), conveniently posted the same day as your question, appears to show how to work it out. He's calculating the height of the ISS whereas you want the ground speed, but he has to use that as part of his calculation, so he also accounts for his location and the Earth's rotation.